# How to resolve SSL handshake failure using urllib request in python 3?

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

**Code Application**

Hi stackers, I am designing a web scraper that sends notifications to a user based on a specific word-based criteria. I have been successfully web-scraping a test website for a while now, however, when I went to run my code yesterday, I got an unexpected error that I have been unsuccessful in resolving. I still am unsure as to why this error is occurring as nothing in my code has changed - which leads me to believe something about the website may have changed. The error appears to occur when I'm trying to read the contents of the website after using urllib's Request.

**The Code**

```
url = "http://www.ksl.com"

import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
html = html.decode('utf-8')
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1260, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 377, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 988, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH TO SCRIPT", line 59, in <module>
    html = urlopen(req).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 504, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 696, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1256, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)>
```

**Attempts I've Made to Fix Error**

So I've installed MacPorts in an attempt to change the SSL path that python is using, this didn't work and I'm not sure if this is the right solution path.

I put these two lines of code in to see what python is actually doing:

```
v = sys.version
print(v)

import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
```

These two lines give me the following output:

```
3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

I think the issue may be that python is using the mac default version of OpenSSL that is unable to complete the handshake, however I still have a lot to learn about this stuff, so I'm not entirely sure.

Please help me stackers, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, your OpenSSL version is too old. Here's an example using two versions of macOS's `openssl`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ksl.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
2908:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:

$ /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/bin/openssl s_client -connect ksl.com:443
[...]
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If you install a newer version of python, e.g. with `brew install python3`, you should have better luck:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017'
```

With this version, your script works just fine.

Comment: Hey Christian thank you for the response! I successfully ran the "brew install python3" command in terminal, however it doesn't seem to have updated the version of OpenSSL I have (it is still printing the same version). I think this has something to do with the order of things in the $PATH, but I'm not sure how to fix it.